# Hover effect only triggered when hovering on top half of card

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-transforms

I have a secrtion on my site with three flip cards. The images are initially in grayscale but on hover, they are colored. However when i hover over the front of the card, the effect is only triggered on the top half of the card. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

```css
    cards-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    .card-wrapper{
        flex:0 1 250px;
        margin: 10px;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
    .card{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;  
        transition: transform 0.8s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #c4c4c4;
    }
    .flip{
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
    .front {
        background-size:cover;
        background-position: center;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(90%) brightness(70%);
        filter: grayscale(90%) brightness(70%);
        transition: 300ms ease-in;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .front:hover{
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(20%) ;
        filter: grayscale(20%) ;
    }

    .card-1 .front{
        background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/nCya9c9AadA);
    }

    .card-2 .front{
        background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/d0iASNy8p50);
    }
    .card-3 .front{
        background-image:url(https://source.unsplash.com/pa_McjjynOA);

    }
    .back{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(pink, rgb(168, 235, 255), lavender);
        /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
```

```html
      <div class="container-2 rellax" data-rellax-speed="2" data-rellax-zindex="3">
        <div class="title">
          <h1>Lotus
            <i class="fas fa-spa fa-1x"></i>
            Yoga</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="cards-container">
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card card-1">
              <div class="front">
                <h2>pee</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="back">
                <h2>poo</h2>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card card-2">
              <div class="front">
                <h2>bleep</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="back">
                <h2>bloop</h2>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-wrapper">
            <div class="card card-3">
              <div class="front">
                <h2>pee</h2>
              </div>

              <div class="back">
                <h2>poo</h2>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

When I comment out this code, the hover effect works properly. However, then the backside of the card is upside down, so this code is necessary.

```
    .back{
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
        transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    }
```

does anyone have any explanation/solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by hiding the back side and then show on hovering the front.
You can to this as follow:

```
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
    display: none;
}
.front:hover .back{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This works. However, the back of the card doesn't show during the flip animation on mouse out and it looks glitchy.

Comment: I tweaked this solution for a better one, will share!

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked Asif's solution and this works best:

I removed transform from back:

```css
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(pink, rgb(168, 235, 255), lavender);
}
```

and added it on hover

```css
.card:hover .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
```